# Handle >200K images and live tiles

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store App with live tiles. Tiles contain images but some of them are larger than 200K so tiles cannot use them.

Which is the simpliest way to reach the suitable size?

I read about resize picture or set jpeg compression quality but these have serious overhead in Win8.

Comment: *"I read about resize picture or set jpeg compression quality but these have serious overhead in Win8"* - Do they?  Did you try it?  What was the result?  JPEG compression of tiny images is pretty damn fast.

Comment: 100% agree with @Ed S. Try to reduce image quality/size and post your code if it is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

In my current project (winrt) I have similar problem and solved it by resizing images during binding (in getter of nested field)

```
  get
     {
          return new BitmapImage(....) { DecodePixelWidth = 200 };
     }
```

Hope it's help you too.